# Insertar datos en BD segun el indice enviado

Tags: php, base-de-datos

resulta que me gustaria hacer un insert en la base de datos segun el id del trabajador es decir insertar una linea por cada id. Adjunto código

**PHP**.

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM inn_treballador ";
  $res=$bd->ejecutar($sql);
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["tre_operario"];
  }
  $sql="SELECT * FROM inn_document_treballador_nominas WHERE nom_id_tre=$id";
  $res=$bd->ejecutar($sql);
  if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
// actualizar usuario
  }else{
        // Nomina por usuario
        $fecha_nom = $_POST['fecha_nom'];
        $operario = $_POST['op_'.$id];
        $trabajo_retri = $_POST['trabajo_retri_'.$id];

           $sql_ins="INSERT INTO inn_document_treballador_nominas VALUES (NULL,'$fecha_nom','$operario', '$trabajo_retri');";
           $bd->ejecutar($sql_ins);
     }
```

[image: id]
[image: id]

Como podeis observar cada uno tiene su índice, me gustaria introducirlo al mismo tiempo ya que se envian por POST correctamente pero en base de datos una linea por índice.

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres es bajar el cierre `}` del `while` hasta despues de la consulta INSERT INTO para que vaya cogiendo todos los casos en lugar de solo el último.

Comment: Te lo volví a editar @masterguru muevo el } bajo y me salta error

Comment: Perdona, has cambiado mucho codigo... mi anterior comentario se basaba en el codigo que habia en ese momento, no el de ahora que poco tiene que ver pues has metido un select por en medio.  Aun asi veo que aun estamos a tiempo de arreglarlo... te lo pongo en una respuesta para que se va todo, sino va a ser dificil de explicar via comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inn_treballador ";
$res = $bd->ejecutar($sql);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["tre_operario"];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM inn_document_treballador_nominas WHERE nom_id_tre = $id";
    $res1 = $bd->ejecutar($sql1);
    if ($res1->num_rows > 0) {
        // actualizar usuario
    } else {
        // Nomina por usuario
        $fecha_nom = $_POST['fecha_nom'];
        $operario = $_POST['op_'.$id];
        $trabajo_retri = $_POST['trabajo_retri_'.$id];
        $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO inn_document_treballador_nominas VALUES (NULL,'$fecha_nom','$operario', '$trabajo_retri');";
        $bd->ejecutar($sql_ins);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cerrando al final el while no me funciona me salta este error, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean, deberia hacer otro while entonces?

Comment: Las variables de la consulta se repetian... reacarga esta pagina, y mira si ahora la respuesta esta bien